# ldapadd adds entries without userPasswords

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a LDAP database, imported from this LDIF:

```
dn: olcDatabase=hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap-jenkins
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
olcRootPW:: e1NTSEF9YmkzUDlFa1ZycDJMb2JDRDZoRmJmNkpLR2xhNWV2Q1doQzBOWmc9PQ==
olcDbIndex: uid eq
olcDbIndex: mail eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" write
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
olcAccess: to *
  by self write
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
  by dn="cn=jenkins,dc=example,dc=com" read
  by * none
```

I'm trying to import this entry with `# ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f darth_vader.ldif`:

```
dn: mail=darth.vader@death.star,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: person
cn: Anakin
sn: Skywalker
mail: darth.vader@death.star
userPassword: e1NTSEF9LzVHNXczbUViYnlJaE5CM0RBdGRjS3I3c1hYN085em90d3B3QWc9PQ==
```

The entry is imported, but without `userPassword`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue was the way I connect to the database, not with the import. I was connecting using `jenkins` user which does not have access to the `userPassword` attribute as specified in the ACL. He just does not see that attribute.

What I need to do is to add some permissions for him:

```
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by dn="cn=jenkins,dc=example,dc=com" read
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" write
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
```

Read is sufficient, but, probably, lower level like `auth` or `compare` will work too.